# Gluck twists for higher genus surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I am familiar with the Gluck twist of a sphere in a 4-manifold and I am curious if there is a generalization to an arbitrary oriented surface in a 4-manifold.  Namely, for $g > 0$ letting $\Sigma_g$ be the closed orientable surface of genus $g$, are there automorphisms of $\Sigma_g \times S^1$ that do not extend over $\Sigma_g \times D^2$?

Comment: They all extend if $g>1$ but there are infinitely many, up to isotopy, which do not extend if $g=1$.